# Iframe resizer not defined

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I was trying to add our website in to one of our client website and used iframe resizer. Their website uses Brightspot CMS. So That gives  iframe-resizer undefined error.

When I made some changes to iframe resizer js file, 
which is I removed

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([],factory);
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') { //Node for browserfy
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        window.iFrameResize = window.iFrameResize || factory();
}
```

and only kept

```
window.iFrameResize = window.iFrameResize || factory();
```

With this change everything works fine. Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the website you adding this uses requireJS, then you must load this script with RequireJS.